# Replace a character inside a string using C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to know how to replace `,` characters inside array brackets `[]` with another character, say `.`. The string expression I have is below:

> Attributes["412324 - PENNDOT I-95", "Category"].Value, Attributes["412324 - PENNDOT I-95", "Category"].Code

The expected output should be:

> Attributes["412324 - PENNDOT I-95". "Category"].Value, Attributes["412324 - PENNDOT I-95". "Category"].Code

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Post some code of what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, and it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[[^\[\]]*),(?=[^\[\]]*\])");
return regex.Replace(<your sample string>, ".");
```

Within the regex pattern, to the left of the `,` is a positive lookbehind zero-width assertion that means there must be a `[` and then zero or more characters that are neither `[` nor `]` leading up to the comma.

After the comma, a positive lookahead zero-width assertion that means there can be zero or more characters that are neither `[` nor `]` then there must be a closing `]`.

Zero-width assertions mean that the pattern must precede or follow the matched text, but are not part of the match. Since we are only matching the `,` our replacement is just the `.`

Comment: Thank you, Jay.  This solution works!  It gets me motivated to learn more about Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

if it's always in this sheme, then faster would be String.Replace:

```
string sin = "Attributes["412324 - PENNDOT I-95", "Category"].Value, Attributes["412324 - PENNDOT I-95", "Category"].Code";
string sout = sin.Replace("\", \"","\". \"");
```

you can do the same with RegEx, but it would be slower and still it can break if the input string changes it's structure

Comment: This is a valid solution, but I disagree with your last comment. Your solution would break more readily than a good regex solution.

Comment: yes, I know about that, RegEx will work in most general cases, but if input string will always look like this - OP can consider using this, much simpler (and faster) solution. Anyway, obwiously correct answer to OP's question is Jay's answer - it makes heavy use of RegEx to replace only correct commas

Comment: As you mention, this solution should work, however, sometimes, the input string may / may not have extra spaces and the quotion marks could be single quotes.  I didn't make it clear in my question.